# How to write a password which contain "&" in app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

How to write a password which contain "&" in app.config

```
<add connectionString="Data Source=x.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=Testing002;User Id=hello;Password=&a:;" name="ConString"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Comment: still the same error, what is the difference

Comment: @ControlPoly: The different is that `&amp;` is the way you should encode `&` in XML files.